# Linear Extension

Tags: combinatorics

I haven't encountered the concept of linear extensions in combinatorics before and was confused by the following questions:

How many linear extensions exist concerning a chain on n elements and a chain on m elements? Assume there are no possible comparabilities between the chains.

How many linear extensions exist concerning a chain on n elements and an antichain on m elements? Assume no comparabilities between the chain and antichain.

I'm aware of what chains and antichains mean in terms of posets, but just don't know what is meant by linear extensions. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a poset that is the disjoint union of two chains, one with $m$ and the other with $n$ elements. If $m>n$, the Hasse diagram of your poset looks something like this:

```
      *   
      |   
      *  
      |  
      ·  
      ·  
      ·  
      |  
      *   *  
      |   |  
      *   *  
      |   |  
      ·   ·  
      ·   ·  
      ·   ·  
      |   |  
      *   *  
      m   n
```

Technically this poset is a set $X$ together with a partial order $R$ on $X$. A *linear extension* of it is a pair $\langle X,L\rangle$, where $L$ us a *linear* order on $X$ such that $R\subseteq L$. In other words $L$ has all of the comparability relationships that $R$ has and enough more to make it a linear rather than just a partial order. If the two chains are $C_m$ and $C_n$, and the partial order is $\preceq$, one simple linear extension is the linear order $\le$ on $X=C_m\cup C_n$ that you get by defining $x\le y$ if and only if either $x,y\in C_m$ and $x\le y$, or $x,y\in C_n$ and $x\le y$, or $x\in C_m$ and $y\in C_n$. In other words, we just move $C_n$ ‘above’ $C_m$ in the Hasse diagram.

In this case the any linear ordering of the $m+n$ elements of $C_m\cup C_n$ will work ***provided*** that it preserves the internal orders of the changes $C_m$ and $C_n$. If $m=2$ and $n=3$, for instance, and the chains are $a<b$ and $1<2<3$, any permutation of $\{a,b,1,2,3\}$ that has $a$ somewhere before $b$, $1$ somewhere before $2$, and $2$ somewhere before $3$ yields a linear extension of the partial order.

I’ll stop there to give you a chance to work it out on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmm...it's not immediately obvious to me how to compute the total number of permutations that meets the constraints. I'm thinking of a recursive algorithm using an array....For example, let X = ${x_1,x_2, ..., x_n}$ and Y = ${y_1, y_2, ..., y_m}$, where all elements are "sorted" from least to greatest. Then I could designate some kind of array as follows: R[i][j] = the number of linear orders of $x_1$ thru $x_i$ and $y_1$ thru $y_j$. And I could recurse starting from the last elements...but I have a feeling that this is neither necessary nor intended by the question?

Comment: @user3280193: Indeed it’s not; you’re making it much too hard. Look at the miniature example in my answer. Any linear extension is going to have $5$ slots. If I tell you that the members of $C_2$ occupy the third and fifth slots (reading from small to large), can you tell me exactly what the whole linear order has to be?

Comment: Oh, so it just amounts to C(5, 2)? Or in the general case, C(m+n, n)?

Comment: @user3280193: You’ve got it. Once you know which slots are occupied by one chain, the order of those elements in those slots is fixed, as is the order of the elements of the other chain in *their* slots.

Comment: Thanks! Could you shed some light also on what this implies for the second question, regarding n-element chain and m-element antichain?

Comment: @user3280193: You’re welcome! In that case you have essentially $m+1$ disjoint chains, one of $n$ elements and $m$ of $1$ element each. Getting a linear extension is then just a matter of deciding which $m$ slots will get the members of the antichain ***and*** deciding in which order to fill those slots, since the elements of the antichain can be arranged in any order.

Comment: Ah, ok...so then would we be looking at something like m! * C(m + n, n)? Since the m antichain elements can be permuted? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user3280193: No, you’re not missing anything: that’s exactly right. You can write it in various ways: $m!\binom{m+n}n=m!\binom{m+n}m=\frac{(m+n)!}{n!}\;,$$ for instance.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user3280193: You’re welcome!